# SQL Server Stored Procedure Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I know that this question has been asked a few times, but the suggestions don't seem to be working for me.  I have an 83 line stored procedure that I need to call and pass a start and an end date into it.  The procedure works great if I hard code the dates; however, when I try to pass the dates as variables I receive the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I am calling my stored procedure as follows:

```
exec dbo.CreateReport @startDate = '10/01/2013', @endDate = '12/31/2013'
```

I am creating my stored procedure as follows:

```
create procedure dbo.CreateReport 
    @startDate smalldatetime = NULL, 
    @endDate smalldatetime = NULL
```

The block of code where the error is occurring:

```
declare vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor cursor for 
            select a.laborleveldsc1,a.laborleveldsc2,a.laboracctid, sum(b.durationsecsqty)/3600 as totalhours
            from vp_laboraccount a, timesheetitem b
            where a.laboracctid=b.laboracctid and b.eventdtm >=''' + @@startDate + ''' and b.eventdtm <= ''' + @@endDate + ''' and employeeid = @personid
            group by a.laborleveldsc1,a.laborleveldsc2,a.laboracctid
            open vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor
            fetch next from vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor into @laborleveldsc1,@laborleveldsc2,@laboracctid,@totalhours
            while @@fetch_status=0
            begin
            --print results
                select @message = @personid + ',' + @personcstmdatatxt + ',' + @searchfullnm + ',' + @prdohh + ',' + @prjob1 + ',' + @laborleveldsc1 + ',' + @laborleveldsc2 + ',' + @laboracctid + ',' + @totalhours + ',' + @companhiredtm
                --print @message
                insert into dbo.tabResults (messages) Values(@message)
            fetch next from vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor into @laborleveldsc1,@laborleveldsc2,@laboracctid,@totalhours
            end
            close vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor
            deallocate vp_laboraccount_timesheetitem_cursor
```

The specific line where the error is occurring:

```
where a.laboracctid=b.laboracctid and b.eventdtm >=''' + @@startDate + ''' and b.eventdtm <= ''' + @@endDate + ''' and employeeid = @personid
```

The two variables in question are the @@startDate and the @@endDate.

I have tried several things, including passing my variables in as varchar, as well as doing both a convert and a cast on the variables, but nothing seems to be working for me.  I have tried both a single @ and a double @@ sign because those often give me problems.  I have tried different date formats, but every time I get a variation of the same error message.  If I hard code my date strings into the code it works as expected, and without errors.

I think that I am being very obtuse, and the solution will be obvious once somebody hits me over the head with a shovel, but after a week of trying various things I am ready to ask for help.

What am I doing wrong, and what do I have to do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: remove the quotes. just use eventdtm >= @startDate (same thing for @endDate). No need to concatenate when you aren't using dynamic sql here. Also you only need a single @. This is a local variable.

Comment: You also should use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins And you should use meaningful aliases to avoid incredible amounts of pain. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only truly safe formats for date/time literals in SQL Server, at least for `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, are: `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]` - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Use the single `@` for your variable.

```
exec dbo.CreateReport @startDate='20131001', @endDate='20131231'
```

And your `where` clause should be like so:

```
where a.laboracctid=b.laboracctid
  and b.eventdtm >= @startDate
  and b.eventdtm <= @endDate
  and employeeid = @personid
```

---

Also, you should use proper joins instead of old-style joins and use meaningful aliases.

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
- [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Removing the quotes and the concatenator worked.  I tried variations on that, but never actually tried removing them completely.  Thanks to both  scsimon and SqlZim for your suggestions and help.  I will also take a look at  the other suggestions, as I am always willing to make my stuff better.